# Get number of base of an integer

Tags: swift, converters, radix

I´m making a multiple base converter in Xcode with Swift 8. When you enter your number you can pick the base of your number and the base you want to convert to. I want to know if there is any way to grab the base of your current number.

Comment: If the user is entering the number, isn't it safe to assume its in decimal (base=10)?

Comment: You can't. If the user enters the text `100`, then how can you guess what base it is? It could be base 2, 8, 10, 16, 64, or any other base.

Comment: you cann't determine base of a number unless you manually entered it.

Comment: I ask because my app works perfect when you determine a possible base for the number, but if for example I enter the number 744, and then you determine that that number is base 2, the app crashes because it is impossible that that number be that base, any way to fix that issue?

Comment: If your app is guessing that a number is base 2 when there are digits other than 0 or 1 then you have bigger issues.